# Почему URLSearchParams неверно билдит урл?

Tags: javascript, php

Вот такой пример: `new URLSearchParams({props: ['x', 'y']}).toString()`. 
На выходе получаем `props=x%2Cy`. 
Но пардон, какая к черту запятая между элементами массива? 
Должно же быть так: `props[]=x&props[]=y`. 
Иначе PHP не распарсивает нормально эту переменную как массив...

Comment: То, что `props[]=x&props[]=y` парсится именно так, как требуется для php-скрипта - это заслуга php-движка. Другие веб-сервера вполне могут работать с урлами вида `props=x&props=y` совершенно иначе.

Comment: @u_mulder но это вроде как стандарт... Почему в JS API отступили от стандарта? И чем мне тогда билдить урл чтобы все работало как мне надо?

Comment: Где зафиксирован этот стандарт? Rfc какой-то есть?

Comment: @u_mulder алло! Всю жизнь так PHP работал. С самых первых версий. Это не зависит ни от фреймворков ни от чего то еще. Это просто стандарт. А по скольку PHP был, скажем так, первопроходцем в веб-разработке все остальные языки обычно придерживаются его стандартов.

Comment: Ещё раз для танкистов - то что пхп работает так, не гарантирует того что все остальные работают так же.

Comment: @u_mulder еще раз, как мне сбилдить урл в нужном формате???

Comment: A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]").  **This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.** - [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). Так что да, стандарт прямо запрещает использовать квадратные скобки.

Comment: @Yaant но PHP работает только так!!!

Comment: Ну тогда собирайте нужную строку вручную.

Comment: @Yaant мда. Тяжелый случай

Comment: наши бэкэндщики, на ПХП, без проблем парсят строку сформированную URLSearchParams - даже вопросов никаких не задали